Регистрация и аутентификация по JWT в OAuth2 django restframework
Всем привет! У меня есть задача, реализовать регистрацию и аутентификацию с использованием JWT и OAuth2 в drf. Я правильно понимаю что могу использовать Simple JWT для получения токенов и django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 для социальной аутентификации? И поправьте пожалуйста если я не правильно понял логику: social-oauth2 позволяет аутентифицироваться через соц сети, а Simple JWT выдает токены.

Добро пожаловать на сайт, Михаил Тутаринов, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
